# RewriteRule: deny everything except root, a file and all files in a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to deny everything; except the following should be allowed:

```
1 http://example.com/
2 http://example.com/favicon.ico
3 http://example.com/downloads/secret/test.txt
```

via

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(favicon\.ico|downloads/secret/[^/]+\.[a-z]+)?$ - [F,L]
```

Number 2 and 3 work just fine. But I can't reach http://example.com/

How do I modifiy my RewriteRule to make the first example work as well?

Comment: Those 3 should be or should not be allowed?

Comment: Should be allowed, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:|favicon\.ico|downloads/secret/test\.txt|index.php)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

change `index.php` to what ever index file you are using (like `index.html`, `index.pl` etc)

Comment: Looks good, but still doesn't work for http://example.com/ Could this be a limitation of XAMPP?

Comment: @fanti check for the update. Also, change `index.php` to what ever index file you are using (like index.html, index.pl etc).